# How to implement a custom performance function to be used with Matlab's neural network toolbox?

Tags: neural-network, matlab

The default performance function is `mse`, but I want to use a different metric for calculating performance.
I also noticed that `trainlm` doesn't support custom performance functions.
An additional question is which training functions support custom performance functions? Does `traingdx` supports a custom performance function?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that [`trainbr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/nnet/ref/trainbr.html),[`trainscg`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/nnet/ref/trainscg.html) and [`traingdx`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/nnet/ref/traingdx.html) allow using a customized performance function in conjunction with the  `performFcn` property. More specifically, you must associate your neural network (let's call it `net`) with your customized performance function like this:

```
net.performFcn=`MyPerformanceFunction'
```

The modified performance function should have a header that looks like this (similar to the [*regularized MSE function*](http://dali.feld.cvut.cz/ucebna/matlab/toolbox/nnet/msereg.html)):

```
perf = MyPerformanceFunction(e, x, pp)
```

You can also specify custom performance parameters as necessary, like this:

```
perfStruct.varA = 1;
perfStruct.varB = 2; 
net.performParam = perfStruct;
```

This is also documented [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1BYOH/index.html?product=NN&solution=1-1BYOH).